# IATKOS and AppStore question

Tags: iphone, app-store

My question is if  any information regarding what is used to develop (iatkos) your apps? I have a fully working IATKOS install and wanna try the appstore playground, but I'm afraid of having any sort of troubles (legal ones) after publishing my first app....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No No prblm at all. you can easily publish your application on apps store. Even you cal also update ur IATKOSH software. its working fine.

Thx